# SQL CLR - Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlclr

I've created a user defined function and executed. It returns the below error message. Need your support.

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlBoolean SqlFunctValidateUserCred() 
    {
            bool verify = Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword("test", "test1");
            return verify;
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 11 A .NET Framework error occurred
>   during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate
>   "SqlFunctValidateUserCred":  System.FormatException: Invalid length
>   for a Base-64 char array or string. System.FormatException:     at
>   System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32
>   inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)    at
>   System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
>   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)    at
>   System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(String hashedPassword,
>   String password)    at UserDefinedFunctions.SqlFunctValidateUserCred()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.verifyhashedpassword(v=vs.111).aspx):

> Parameters
>   hashedPassword
>   Type: System.String
>   The previously-computed RFC 2898 hash value as **a base-64-encoded string**.

Read.

Answer (score -1):

You can try following :

```
public static void AddUsersToDatabase(string databaseserver, string databasename, string usertobeadded)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = 
        new SqlConnection("server=" + databaseserver + 
                        "; database=" + databasename + 
                        "; User ID=WPDOMAIN\\spdev; Integrated Security=SSPI;  password=Password123;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string password = "Password123";
        string sql = "CREATE LOGIN " + usertobeadded + " WITH PASSWORD = '" +
        password + "';  USE " + databasename + "; CREATE USER " + usertobeadded + " FOR LOGIN " + usertobeadded + ";";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how is your post answering the question?